# Pandemic Legacy: Question about missions (Spoilers)

Tags: pandemic-legacy-season-1

We just played a game where a mission card says : destroy it if you completed the mission. We completed the mission, but we lost the game.

For the second try do we have to do the mission again? Or does it count as 1 already finished task and we have to complete only 2 more? Or do we now have to finish all the other 3 missions?

The rules are not so clear: The mission card says we should destroy it once we found him, but in the rule book it says that we should start the second try for the month with exact same briefing and missions as the first one.

Comment: I've changed the title so that it doesn't include spoilers for the game. The community may feel the question should undergo further editing to hide spoilers, but this was a start to prevent users who haven't played this far from being spoiled on game progression.

Comment: @SocioMatt i tried to remove spoilers as much as I could. Hope it is better now

Comment: It's also a good idea to post on the title the month you are interested in, as more people are likely to respond, should they have passed that mark. Otherwise, a generic "spoilers" is too vague, I wouldn't risk it if I were in the middle of a campaign.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must finish the other missions. You still need to finish 3 total, and because that one has been destroyed, there are only 3 missions remaining.

There is some discussion saying the same thing [here](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1585151/second-half-july-question-spoilers).

Comment: "that one hasn't been destroyed" should be "that one has been destroyed", no?

Comment: Yes, thanks, actually saw and fixed that just before you commented.

Comment: actually we had a long discussion and I agree with what you say, but do you agree, that it is a bit misleading that the rulebook says you start the second try with exact same missions? (we have a german game, maybe some small detail got lost in translation)

Comment: Updated with a link. Going off of memory, but the rules I believe say to start with the same mission briefing, not the same missions. The mission briefing is just the 1 card that you get each month with the story for that month.